# Give different path addresses to same storage location

Tags: windows, filesystems

Is it possible to give different addresses to same storage location in Windows. For example address "C:\Dir1" and "D:\Dir2" access the same storage location, let say I have an executable program placed in Dir1 as "C:\Dir1\prog.exe" and then I want to access the program as "D:\Dir2\prog.exe".

Comment: Just a thought, but symbolic links might be a possible way to go here. That is, keep your program in the primary directory and create a symbolic link in the secondary directory. Don't forget to include the proper extension(s) with the symbolic links.

Comment: I do this all of the time exactly as @Anaksunaman suggests.  Either use the `mklink` utility at the command prompt or there is a spiffy shell extension called the [Hardlink Shell Extension](https://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html) that I have used for years when I am too lazy to type.